# Flutter Dropdown Button Remove on press grey color

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to remove this grey button when i'm selecting the value for dropdown button. How can i do it. I try everything
Here its my code

```
InputDecorator(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0))),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      ),
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton<dynamic>(
          value: null,
          isDense: true,
          hint: Text(hintText),
          isExpanded: true,
          items: itemList,
          onChanged: (newValue) {},
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the theme per widget by wrapping it around a [`Theme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) widget to change the [`InkWell`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) effect. Instead of changing the global `MaterialApp.theme`, this way doesn't change the entire app `InkWell` behaviour. So, it's just a matter of changing the [`ThemeData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) `highlightColor`, `hoverColor` and `splashColor`.

Check the result below:

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
InputDecorator(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0))),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  ),
  child: Theme(                           // <- Here
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(     // <- Here
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,    // <- Here
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent, // <- Here
      hoverColor: Colors.transparent,     // <- Here
    ),
    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        value: selectedValue,
        isDense: true,
        isExpanded: true,
        focusColor: Colors.transparent,
        items: const [
          DropdownMenuItem(value: '1', child: Text('menu1')),
          DropdownMenuItem(value: '2', child: Text('menu2')),
          DropdownMenuItem(value: '3', child: Text('menu3')),
          DropdownMenuItem(value: '4', child: Text('menu4')),
        ],
        onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() => selectedValue = newValue),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to change default splashcolor in your ThemeData like this:

```
theme: ThemeData(
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
```

A con with this is setting it in your themedata is if you would like to use different colors in other parts of your code.

Otherwise you could also try to use [SplashFactory](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle/splashFactory.html)

Comment: I've been looking for this for a long time thank you so much

Comment: No problem. If it works I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer. Good luck!

Comment: Note: this will reset every splash effect, better wrap the widget with `Theme`